# custom iOS app availability in public app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

I've an iOS app.
But I've several issues with my "Ready for Sale" app.
My app is distributed as custom app.
But users are unable to install the app with a "redemption code".

I tried to explain to them but very few have got it.
Others were getting discouraged with my custom app implementation. They're asking why it's not available in app store.

So I need to make available my app in app store. So that all user can download the app from the app store like any other app.

How can I make my custom app available in app store for download.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing an app in the AppStore, is fairly simple but there are some conditions:

- You have to be a a registered Apple Developer, which means you have to pay the USD 100 fee, you can join [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)
- Your app must follow App Store guidelines: [read them here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
- Since any apple user can download your app, you must find a way to allow **only** your users to use the app it, it could be a user/password or any way your find appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Once an app has been marked for distribution as a custom app it cannot be made available as a general App Store app.

You can take your existing source code and change the bundle id, effectively making it a new app. You can then set up a new app record in App Store Connect for this new bundle id and submit it for review by Apple.

You should be aware that if the app targets a specific or limited audience then it may not be approved for the App Store.